# Transmit data script Ajax and Script PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to send data from a script using Ajax to a script PHP. And I have this error : Notice: Undefined index: background. Thanks for your help.

```
ajax.php :

<?php
        $mavariable2=$_POST['background'];
        echo $mavariable2;
    ?>

script.js : 

function open_script(){
     // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "ajax.php";
    var back = "blue" ;
    var backgroundf = "&background="+back;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(backgroundf); // Actually execute the request
    //window.location.assign('ajax.php');
}
```

Comment: Try to remove apersand `&` before background in js.

Comment: Or try an ajax call using jquery?

Comment: "var backgroundf = "&background="+back;" replace with  "var backgroundf = "background="+back;"

Answer (score 0):

If you already have `jQuery` as a dependency in your project try using `$.ajax()`.

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { background : 'blue' },
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function( msg ) {
  $( "#log" ).html( msg );
});
```

**More Information: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/**